# Turning off only certain animations in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, animation

I really am not a fan of any kind of hover animations (moving your cursor over elements, making the selection animated) because I think it makes the OS feel slow instead of smooth.

So for example in the new context menu hovering over any element is delayed because of the animation and I wonder if there is a way to turn off only that without affecting the other animations Windows has.

Comment: First of you cannot decrease this setting from 5 seconds to something less, second this isn't my issue

Comment: You cannot do what you wish in native Windows 11 - not possible. Registry changes in this area can also quickly hose your system. Possibly you need a faster computer or much faster disk. This is not an issue for me.

Comment: I have a powerful computer with 240hz display, RTX 3070 and M2 SSD. Its not a system problem its an animation problem, since it takes a few hundred milliseconds for the hover selection to appear it feels delayed which is purely a fault of the animation, this is why I think hover animations should not be a thing. 
I just wonder if its possible to change this at all even with registry tweaks. I can test it on a VM if neccesary.

Comment: I have never been slowed down by this (certainly nothing at all noticeable), but in any event you cannot do natively what you wish.

Comment: Well it is an issue for me though, I guess if this isn't fixable in any way the only solution is to go back to Windows 10